# Checking how long a request from mobile device to server takes only on android device

Tags: android

I am sending an HTTP request from my android device. I sent the UTC timestamp on header request. On server side we checked the time difference. If time difference is greater then 5 second, API does not return the success response.

But on the other hand it is working fine on web browser.